# sort map keys with special characters and spec-char precedence

Tags: javascript, object

```
ES6 Map :

const map = new Map();
                map.set('first', ['1', '2']);
                map.set('second', ['abc', 'def']);
                map.set('_third', []);
                map.set(')(*', []);
                map.set('he__e', []);

                console.log(map);
```

A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order.

And I sorted the map with below

```
var mapAsc = new Map([...map.entries()].sort());
console.log(mapAsc)
```

but it outputs me

```
0: {")(*" => Array(0)}
1: {"_third" => Array(0)}
2: {"first" => Array(2)}
3: {"he__e" => Array(0)}
4: {"second" => Array(2)}
```

so the '3' index has the special characters init ? I want the output to be

```
0: {")(*" => Array(0)}
1: {"_third" => Array(0)}
2: {"he__e" => Array(0)}
3: {"first" => Array(2)}
4: {"second" => Array(2)}
```

Comment: _“Does JS Map object allows ordering ?”_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map: _“The keys in Map are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus, when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of insertion.”_ (-1 for not making the minimal effort of reading up on that yourself.)

Comment: @misorude I think the OP meant to ask wether Map allows sorting, not wether it is ordered. But yes, Map containing ordered data also implies that you can sort the data; even if that's not provided by the API or trivial.

Comment: @misorude, i edited the question, please see

Comment: Is hard to answer that question when we don't even know why you're using special characters in the first place. Is hard to order a map with keys that have no specific pattern or type.

Comment: _“so the '3' index still has the special characters init”_ - what do you mean by _still_? Of course it has, and it would be weird if it didn’t - _sorting_ is not supposed to change the content of the individual items. _“how can i sort this ?”_ - by what criteria/ logic, what is the result you want?

Comment: @GopiGorantala, [MDN Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) check the part about compare-functions

Comment: I want this output:   0: {")(*" => Array(0)}
1: {"_third" => Array(0)}
2: {"he__e" => Array(0)}
3: {"first" => Array(2)}
4: {"second" => Array(2)}

Comment: _“ want this output”_ - based on _what_? Is that supposed to be an alphabetical sorting of the keys, is it a custom order you specified somewhere, …?

Comment: all keys consisting special characters  should be listed first in my map, and the rest with alphabetical order

Comment: @misorude, don't be rude please.. understand the question before you give this question a -1. I never asked for ordering, I wanted to sort the map

Comment: @Thomas, .sort() won't work as I have object of objects in the map..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jiveTags = new Map();
```

I am copying here an example data of my object:

```
 jiveTags = {
          dev: {
              tagName: "dev",
              contentID: Array(7),
              contentTypes: Array(2),
              tagURL: Array(1),
              occurrences: 7
            }
         }
```

//

```
var sortJiveTags = new Map();
    for (var tagValue in jiveTags) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tagValue.length; i++) {
          if (/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi.test(tagValue.charAt(i))) {
                  sortJiveTags[tagValue] = jiveTags[tagValue];
           }
         }
     }// 0(n2) order of n2
```

Once I copy all the special charactered keys in to another Map object, I then go ahead and copy the rest of other keys with the following loop.

```
for (var tagValue in jiveTags) {
        if (jiveTags[tagValue] !== sortJiveTags[tagValue]) {
            sortJiveTags[tagValue] = jiveTags[tagValue];
        }
    }
```